# Outlook global address book for company w/o Exchange

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, contacts

What's a good solution for a global contact list (company email addresses) w/o having Exchange server?  Oh yeah, this for the masses, not people who actually know how to import a contact list - and for a range of Outlook versions (2003 - 2010)

Comment: I chose Valentin's answer, however I was really hoping for something that I run as a server locally.

Comment: In which case Scalix (Community Edition) might be better suited to your needs:  http://www.scalix.com/

Comment: Scalix does have its advantages. However this groupware solution is considered as being dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative would be migrating to the Zarafa Groupware. The community edition is free and offers a fair amount of features. Enough for normal use, if you ask me. Zarafa contains a Global Address Book.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out [GoogleApps](http://www.google.com/a), this allows 'Contact Sharing' AFAIK.

EDIT 10.04.2012  -  [Scalix](http://www.scalix.com/) could fit your needs to run a server locally. The community edition is free.

Comment: Both acceptable answers, too bad I can only chose one.